# Remote connection to embedded device in field

Tags: authentication, ssh, embedded, ethernet

I would like to ask about the way how to establish **remote connection to Linux based embedded device** in the field.
I have a small **linux board** I want to place in **remote location**. It has an internet access through ethernet. Than I have a **Linux server with public IP** to be able to tunnel connection.
And finally, I want to **connect from my PC to this device**.

I don't feel yet competent enough to code my own tcp sockets etc. to reroute the connection :) ***So what would be the easiest way to do that only with available linux tools?*** And BusyBox toolset on endpoints.

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) would be a easy way to tunnel to the device. You can cross compile it and set it up as a client on the embedded device. Then you install it on your Linux box and set it up as a server.
Finally you install it on your work PC and set up as a client there.

It gives you a virtual network where all clients can talk to each other like they would be on a local network.

Comment: That sounds like simplest and perfect solution :) I am going to dig into it and figure out the details.